# Developing Android application with MySQL database?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm working on an Android project using Android studio and MySQL. I have searched through the internet about ways to retrieve/fetch data from MySQL and display it on an Android device (i.e. display the data in a List or Grid view), but mostly what I've found is that people use JSON objects to do so.

My question is, is there any other way to fetch data from MySQL and display it in a List view or manipulating data between Android and MySQL without using JSON object?

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: You used absolutely zero tags that applied to the question you asked. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a spesified adapter class for populating ListView which is named [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

Good luck there

Emre